# Why is the second from clause not executing in the following LINQ query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
var startingDeck =
                        (from s in Suits().LogQuery("Suit Generation")
                         from r in Ranks().LogQuery("Rank Generation")
                         select new {Suit = s,
                                     Rank = r}).LogQuery("Starting Deck");
```

The output of the log file below does not show the log message that would be created if the second from clause is executed. Why isn't the second from clause executed when the above LINQ query is executed by calling `LogQuery("StartingDeck")`?

Log Output:

```
Executing Query Suit Generation
Executing Query Starting Deck
```

LogQuery is a custom extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> LogQuery<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, string tag) {
            // File.AppendText creates a new file if the file doesn't exist.
            using (var writer = File.AppendText("StartingDeckQuery.log"))
            {
                writer.WriteLine($"Executing Query {tag}");
            }

            return sequence;
        }
```

Suits and Ranks are iterator methods:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Suits() {
            yield return "clubs";
            yield return "diamonds";
            yield return "hearts";
            yield return "spades";
        }

static IEnumerable<string> Ranks() {
            yield return "two";
            yield return "three";
            yield return "four";
            yield return "five";
            yield return "six";
            yield return "seven";
            yield return "eight";
            yield return "nine";
            yield return "ten";
            yield return "jack";
            yield return "queen";
            yield return "king";
            yield return "ace";
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

This part of your query:

```cs
Ranks().LogQuery("Rank Generation")
```

... is going to be called once for each value in the "outer" query, i.e. once per suit. That's how `SelectMany` (the method used when there are multiple `from` clauses) works: it evaluates the "inner" query for each item in the "outer" query. (That's why you can use "the current item in the outer query" as part of the inner query.)

But that will only happen when you start iterating. You haven't shown any code that actually does any iterating, which is why you haven't seen the "Rank Generation" logging... whereas the other two log lines are written just to evaluate "I've got a sequence", effectively - they're eager.

You may find my [Edulinq article on `SelectMany`](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/27/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-9-selectmany/) helpful for more details.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why `Rank()` does not execute. So the inner from clause is only executed in a foreach loop (i.e. only the outer from clause is executed when you call the query directly)? Can you provide more detail on why the other log lines are written to the StartingDeckQuery file?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia: Because those are used to provide "the thing that you would iterate over" - there's nothing lazy about *those* parts of the query. You could rewrite `LogQuery` itself to be lazy by using an iterator method: change `return sequence;` to `foreach (var item in sequence) { yield return item; }` and at that point you won't get *anything* logged until you start iterating.

Comment: I see, using a `yield return` statement instead of a `return` statement turns the `LogQuery` method into an iterator that is evaluated only when it is needed in a foreach statement. You're right, nothing is logged. Do you mean that `LogQuery("StartingDeck")` shows that the query expression evaluates to an `IEnumerable<'a>` (i.e. shows the query literal is evaluated)? I'm still not sure why the first from clause executes, since LINQ queries are supposed to be lazily executed? Therefore I expect only "Starting Deck" to be logged since the whole query evaluates to a value of type IEumerable<'a>?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia: I don't know how to answer your questions to be honest, because I'm not sure what you're asking. But I suggest you start with simpler queries, without query expressions, and experiment, gradually building up to query expressions. Stack Overflow isn't really designed for the back-and-forth style of questions you're asking.